# Embedded Matplotlib Plot in tkinter Shrinks/Scales Entire Window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to use matplotlib to embed a pyplot chart inside a tkinter frame but as soon as the graph is created the scale of the entire window seems to reduce. The snippet below demonstrates this behaviour.

Does anyone know why this might be? It almost appears to be related to matplotlib figure windows having a different scale than the rest of my PC

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from functools import partial

def plot_data(parent):
    data =[[1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4]]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.plot(data)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=parent)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1260x780")

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

leftframe = Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief='solid')
leftframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+E+S+W)

rightframe = Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief='solid')
rightframe.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+E+S+W)

left_button = Button(leftframe, text='plot', command=partial(plot_data, rightframe))
left_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've worked out this is related to a matplotlib scaling issue with high resolution screens - although I do not have a solution.

High res screens tend to have there UI scaled up (e.g. at 200%), however matplotlib plots avoid this scaling and create a graph at the original size (i.e, 100%) which weirdly causes the whole tkinter gui to revert to default scaling of 100%

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am running in to the same problem.